# Why is my spider_idle / on-demand / URL-feeding like gradually shutting down?

Tags: python, scrapy, signals

I have an `spider_idle` signal set up to feed another batch of urls to the spider. However, this seems to work fine at the beginning, but then the `Crawled (200)...` messages appear more and more rarely to finally stop appearing. I've got 115 test URLs to distribute, and as Scrapy says it `Crawled 38 pages...` out of it. Below is the code of the spider and the scrapy log.

In general, I'm implementing 2-stage crawling, first pass only downloads urls to the `urls.jl` file, second pass is to perform scraping on those URls. I'm now approaching coding of the second spider.

```
import json
import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider


class A2ndexample_comSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = '2nd_example_com'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = cls(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.idle_consume, signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler
        # read from file
        self.urls = []

        with open('urls.jl', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.urls.append(json.loads(line))
        # How many urls to return from start_requests()
        self.batch_size = 5

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            if 0 == len(self.urls):
                return
            url = self.urls.pop(0)
            yield Request(url["URL"])

    def idle_consume(self):
        # Everytime spider is about to close check our urls 
        # buffer if we have something left to crawl
        reqs = self.start_requests()
        if not reqs:
            return
        logging.info('Consuming batch... [left: %d])' % len(self.urls))
        for req in reqs:
            self.crawler.engine.schedule(req, self)
        raise DontCloseSpider
```

**The logs:**

```
INFO: Spider opened
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-140-m-wroclaw-ID3EMF6.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/wynajem/mieszkanie/dolnoslaskie/?nrAdsPerPage=72&search[order]=filter_float_price%3Adesc> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/wynajem-obiekt-5-mieszkan-dla-firmy-legnica-ID3Khvk.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/komfortowy-apartament-sky-tower-41-pietro-ID3ytn1.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/apartament-z-przepieknym-widokiem-z-45-pietra-ID3PWvI.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 110])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-139-04-m-wroclaw-ID3A6dp.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/centrum-willowy-lokal-dostepny-dla-firmy-ID3TgV4.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/wynajem-pietro-na-16-osob-legnica-ID3KcPe.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/wynajem/mieszkanie/dolnoslaskie/?nrAdsPerPage=72&search%5Border%5D=filter_float_price%3Adesc&page=2> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/apartament-trzypokojowy-na-44-pietrze-sky-tower-ID3qXA8.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 105])
DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.example.com/wynajem/mieszkanie/dolnoslaskie/?nrAdsPerPage=72&search[order]=filter_float_price%3Adesc> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-3-pokoje-ul-zatorska-wysoki-standard-ID3GBfa.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/nowe-mieszkanie-2-pokoje-wroclaw-ul-gornicza-ID2NeJT.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/sprzedam-mieszkanie-bezczynszowe-gromadka-ID3S1sA.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-ID3ALrp.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 100])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/2-pok-balkonosobna-kuchniawindado-urzadzenia-ID3Scza.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-47-m-wroclaw-ID3RTOY.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 95])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 90])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/luksusowy-apartament-101m2-centrum-obok-renomy-ID3O1yI.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-70-m-wroclaw-ID3SS4A.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 85])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 80])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 75])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-103-m-wroclaw-ID2ZhbS.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/wynajem/mieszkanie/dolnoslaskie/?nrAdsPerPage=72&search%5Border%5D=filter_float_price%3Adesc&page=3> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/luksusowe-przestronne-dwa-garaze-ID3LwIs.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 70])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-118-74-m-wroclaw-ID2W9Fd.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/ekskluzywny-apartament-z-dostepem-do-silowni-i-spa-ID3pGmQ.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-170-m-wroclaw-ID3MBI0.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 65])
INFO: Crawled 25 pages (at 25 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/loftowe-mieszkanie-krzyki-100-m2-ID3Tfc0.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/nieruchompsc-dla-pracownikow-od-zaraz-ID3TrcA.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/stare-miasto-3-pok-69m2-luxurious-apartment-ID3Qn4o.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/loftowe-100-metrowe-mieszkanie-idealne-na-biuro-ID3Txu4.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 60])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/lesnica-ul-niepierzynska-123-m2-6-pokoi-ogrod-ID3OoI8.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/mieszkanie-63-m-wroclaw-ID3Tbne.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/wynajem/mieszkanie/dolnoslaskie/?nrAdsPerPage=72&search%5Border%5D=filter_float_price%3Adesc&page=4> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/komfortow-apartament-do-wynajecia-3km-od-wroclawia-ID3SA0M.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 55])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/zamienie-mieszanie-2-pokoje-40m2-bielawa-na-wieksz-ID3yyFN.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/apartament-sky-tower-z-wanna-przy-oknie-i-sauna-ID2Z7EA.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 50])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 45])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/ul-ksiecia-witolda-3pok-75m2-wysoki-standard-3700-ID3PK2g.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/komfortowe-mieszkanie-do-wynajecia-ID3Lcvk.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 40])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 35])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 30])
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/oferta/hit-klimatyczne-w-sercu-wroclawia-2-pok-ID3SkJ2.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 25])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 20])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 15])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 10])
INFO: Crawled 38 pages (at 13 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 5])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
(...)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Crawled 38 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
INFO: Consuming batch... [left: 0])
...
```

I've expected that the spider will crawl all 115 URLs, not only 38. Also, if it doesn't want to crawl anymore, and the singal-handler function doesn't raise `DontCloseSpider`, then shouldn't it at least shut-down then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing requests are not failing, otherwise you would see information about it in the logs as well. They are not being sent at all.

If you watch your log closely, you will notice this message:

```
DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.example.com/wynajem/mieszkanie/dolnoslaskie/?nrAdsPerPage=72&search[order]=filter_float_price%3Adesc> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
```

The missing requests are being skipped because they are considered duplicates. See the documentation of the [`DUPEFILTER_CLASS`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) setting for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! TIL: `uniq -d` needs a `sort |` first.